# Python unicode conversion

Tags: python, string, python-unicode

I have the following unicode: `s = u'\\u5b50'`.
I want to convert `s` to `m = u'\u5b50'`.
How do I do it?

```py
s = u'\\u5b50'
m = u'\u5b50'
print len(s) # 6
print len(m) # 1
print s # \u5b50
print m # 子
```

Comment: Do you have *JSON data* perhaps? What is the wider context?

Comment: Yes, I am getting this from a field of a JSON file.

Comment: Then just decode as JSON. Can you show us more data and how you decode that?

Comment: What do you mean by decode as JSON?

Comment: You'll need to provide more context, as it stands now this is a [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It appears to me you are not decoding JSON correctly **or** you have double-encoded JSON. Without more context I can't help you.

Comment: Okay, I will add more details.

Comment: @snakecharmerb: that would apply if this wasn't a JSON problem. That solution won't be correct if this is JSON as that uses UTF-16 surrogate pairs. The syntax is closely related, not the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
print s.decode('unicode-escape') # 子
print len(s.decode('unicode-escape')) # 1
```

Comment: Yes, until you hit a UTF-16 surrogate pair, like `'\uD83D\uDC33'`. It then depends on wether or not you are using a wide UCS4 build of Python; you *may* get `u'\ud83d\udc33'` or `u'\U0001f433'`. The first is incorrect.